# How to set Powerpoint normal view with thumbnails pane too

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to set PowerPoint normal view with the code below. The code shows the normal slide, but the left-side thumbnails do not show up in a left-side pane.

```
wapp.ActiveWindow.ViewType = PpViewType.ppViewNormal;
```

I have looked through all the ppViewType options, but none of them produce the desired results.

Does someone know the magic syntax (VBA or C#) to make the normal display look like the display when I click the Normal button on the UI? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get the thumbnails showing if I run 2 view statements. The first sets the view to ppViewSlide (without thumbnails). Then ppViewNormal restores the thumbnails:

```
Sub ShowHideWindows()
    With ActiveWindow
        .ViewType = ppViewSlide
        .ViewType = ppViewNormal
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: John, you're a PowerPoint genius! That strange combination was the magic syntax! Thank you.

Comment: I have the same problem with the Slide Master view. The thumbnails don't show up on the side panel. From normal and sorter views, I tried setting the view type to ppSlideMaster only (no cigar). Then I tried setting ppSlide followed by ppSlideMaster (this method worked for Normal view but failed for the Slide Master view). Is there another magic syntax that you know of to get the thumbnails to show in the SlideMaster view? Thank you

Comment: Try _ppViewMasterThumbnails_ instead.

Comment: Thank you again! It works if I use *only* the ppViewMasterThumbnails, without using ppViewSlideMaster option. Where we would be without your PPT help? Thank you.